# I’m trying to execute swap on Pancakeswap with node script but I get error

Tags: node.js

I am new at ethereum development and I am working on a simple script to execute swaps using Pancakeswap.
The code:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

const {ChainId, Token, TokenAmount, Fetcher, Pair, Route, Trade, TradeType, Percent} = 

require('@pancakeswap-libs/sdk');

const Web3 = require('web3');

const {JsonRpcProvider} = require("@ethersproject/providers");

require("dotenv").config();

const provider = new JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/');

const web3 = new Web3('wss://apis.ankr.com/wss/c40792ffe3514537be9fb4109b32d257/946dd909d324e5a6caa2b72ba75c5799/binance/full/main');

const { address: admin } = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);

console.log(`Modulos cargados`);

// Command Line Input

const InputTokenAddr = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(process.argv[2]);

// var BUSD = '0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56';

const OutputTokenAddr = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(process.argv[3]);

// var WBNB = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c';

const InputTokenAmount = process.argv[4]

const Slipage = process.argv[5];

const PANCAKE_ROUTER = process.argv[6];

// const PANCAKE_ROUTER_V2 = '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e';

// const PANCAKE_ROUTER_V1 = '0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F';

// 1/1000 = 0.001

const ONE_ETH_IN_WEI = web3.utils.toBN(web3.utils.toWei('1'));//BN->(BIG NUMBER) || toWei -> Converts any ether value value into wei.

const tradeAmount = ONE_ETH_IN_WEI.div(web3.utils.toBN('1000'));//tradeAmount = ONE_ETH_IN_WEI/1000

console.log(`tradeAmount ` + tradeAmount );

const init = async () => {

    const [INPUT_TOKEN, OUTPUT_TOKEN] = await Promise.all(

        [InputTokenAddr, OutputTokenAddr].map(tokenAddress => (

            new Token(

                ChainId.MAINNET,

                tokenAddress,

                18

            )

        )));

    console.log(` <<<<<------- pair-------->>>>>`);

    const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(INPUT_TOKEN, OUTPUT_TOKEN, provider);

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(pair));

    console.log(` <<<<<------- route-------->>>>>`);

    const route = await new Route([pair], INPUT_TOKEN);

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(route));

    console.log(` <<<<<------- Trade-------->>>>>`);

    const trade = await new Trade(route, new TokenAmount(INPUT_TOKEN, tradeAmount), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(trade));

    //https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/javascript-SDK/trading/

    const slippageTolerance = new Percent(Slipage, '100'); // 

    console.log("slippageTolerance: " + JSON.stringify(slippageTolerance));

    // create transaction parameters

    const amountOutMin = trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageTolerance).raw;

    const path = [INPUT_TOKEN.address, OUTPUT_TOKEN.address];

    const to = admin;

    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20;

    // Create signer

    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(

        Buffer.from(

        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, 

        "hex"

        )

    );

    const signer = wallet.connect(provider);

    // Create Pancakeswap ethers Contract

    const pancakeswap = new ethers.Contract(

        PANCAKE_ROUTER,

        ['function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'],

        signer

    );

    //Allow input token

    if(true)

    {

        console.log(`Allow Pancakeswap <<<<<------- START-------->>>>>`);

        let abi = ["function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)"];

        let contract = new ethers.Contract(INPUT_TOKEN.address, abi, signer);

        let aproveResponse = await contract.approve(PANCAKE_ROUTER, ethers.utils.parseUnits('1000.0', 18), {gasLimit: 100000, gasPrice: 5e9});

        console.log(JSON.stringify(aproveResponse));

        console.log(`Allow Pancakeswap <<<<<------- END-------->>>>>`);

        

    }

    

    if(true)

    {   

        console.log(`Ejecutando transaccion`);      

        var amountInParam = ethers.utils.parseUnits(InputTokenAmount, 18);

        var amountOutMinParam = ethers.utils.parseUnits(web3.utils.fromWei(amountOutMin.toString()), 18);

        

        console.log("amountInParam: " + amountInParam);

        console.log("amountOutMinParam: " + amountOutMinParam);

        console.log("amountOutMin: " + amountOutMin);

                        

        const tx = await pancakeswap.swapExactTokensForTokens(

            amountInParam,

            amountOutMinParam,

            path,

            to,

            deadline,

            { gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(300000), gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("9", "gwei") }

        );

        console.log(`Tx-hash: ${tx.hash}`)

            const receipt = await tx.wait();

            console.log(`Tx was mined in block: ${receipt.blockNumber}`);

    }

        

}

init();
```

Normally I set BUSD as input token
And I use pancakeswap v1 or v2 router as router.
When output token is WBNB or BCH, it seems working well on both v1 and v2 router.
But when I set other token as an output token, I get error.
Plz help me.